# data lost in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have imported data into tables in mysql workbench. And I have clicked apply and saved it. But when I shut down my laptop, all of the data has disappeared. my data lost. What should I do to solve it?
maybe it was because of this
[image]

thank you

Comment: If you imported the data in mysql server then the data is still there.  If the data was not there after you "applied' and 'saved' it then it was never imported, or finished importing into the the server.  Connect to the mysql command line. Workbench is just a tool.  The command line is the truth.

Comment: You problem description is very confusing. The text seems to indicate you have imported an SQL dump while the screenshots shows a message from modeling - these are 2 totally different areas in the tool. So please improve your question with exact details about what you did.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when are conflicts because you used the options:

1. **Include Model...**

or

2. **Import > Reverse Engineer  MYSQL Create Script...**

The only solution is to make EER Diagram again.